# Convert the month difference into integer

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

The dataset with datetime columns as below, I converted to the period as month and calculated the difference. I would like to convert the output as an integer, but failed to do it.

```
ID    StartDate    CurrentDate 
a     2019-03-05   2019-06-18
b     2019-02-05   2019-07-20
c     2019-01-23   2019-07-25

df['start_month_year'] = df['StartDate'].dt.to_period('M')
df['current_month_year'] = df['CurrentDate'].dt.to_period('M')
df['tenure'] = (df['current_month_year'] - df['start_month_year'])
df['tenure'].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way

```
df.CurrentDate.dt.year*12+df.CurrentDate.dt.month-(df.StartDate.dt.year*12+df.StartDate.dt.month)
Out[512]: 
0    3
1    5
2    6
dtype: int64
```

To fix your code adding `astype` before the result became `pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd`

```
(df['CurrentDate'].dt.to_period('M').astype(int)-df['StartDate'].dt.to_period('M').astype(int))
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's have some fun with pandas.tseries.offsets:

Using your code, you can get the number of offsets, n, by using the `apply` to retreive this attribute from the pandas.tseries.offsets object like this:

```
df['start_month_year'] = df['StartDate'].dt.to_period('M')
df['current_month_year'] = df['CurrentDate'].dt.to_period('M')
df['tenure'] = (df['current_month_year'] - df['start_month_year'])
df['tenure'].apply(lambda x: x.n)
```

Output:

```
0    3
1    5
2    6
Name: tenure, dtype: int64
```

However, I like @WeNYoBen's method better.

Comment: n, is the number of offsets.... [see docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html#pandas-tseries-offsets-dateoffset)

Comment: Unfortunate that they changed the behavior to return a DateOffset in `0.24`, requiring the apply to get the integer. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#period-subtraction

Comment: @ALollz  Ah... I am using 0.25.